# python 3 create a GUI to set directory in a program

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, download, tkinter

I would like to create a GUI that pops up asking where to download a file using python. I would like it to be similar to the interface that Google Chrome uses when downloading a file as that looks pretty standard. Is there a default module or add on that I can use to create thus GUI? or will I have to create myself? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You mean the dialog window, in which You chose where to put file, it's tkinter.filedialog (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html), which would give the most native look and feel.

But if You mean the dialog, in which You chose whether to save file in default location or specify another one, there's no such widget, but You may build it on Your own. For that case You probably should dig into Chromium sources, to determine how exactly it acts(https://chromium.googlesource.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of GUI toolkits you could use, including:

- Kivy (modern touch-enabled)
- Tkinter (bundled with Python)

These have file chooser widgets, which you could use that would provide standard-looking interfaces to your file system.

How do you want to run this program?